# how to add subtotal row in a df smartly

Tags: r

I have df like the one on the left. I would like to add subtotal row for each subject (highlighted in yellow in the right-side table).Currently my codes are able to achieve my goal but in a very silly way. I have to do the summary one by one.  Is there a smarter way?

[image]

```
# Data:
df<-structure(list(SUBJECT = c("ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", 
"Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Math", "Sci", "Sci", "Sci", 
"Sci", "Sci"), Level = c("Grade 1", "Grade 2", "Grade 3", "Grade 4", 
"Grade 5", "Grade 1", "Grade 2", "Grade 3", "Grade 4", "Grade 5", 
"Grade 1", "Grade 2", "Grade 3", "Grade 4", "Grade 5"), Total = c(2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), Class1 = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Class2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Class3 = c(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), Class4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Class5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

ClassLev<-c("Class1","Class2", "Class3", "Class4", "Class5"))) 

## Output
df2<-df %>% 
  group_by(SUBJECT) %>%
  do(add_row(.data = .,
             SUBJECT = .$SUBJECT,
             Level = "All Grades",
             `Class1` = sum(.$`Class1`),
             `Class2` = sum(.$`Class2`),
             `Class3` = sum(.$`Class3`),
             `Class4` = sum(.$`Class4`),
             `Class5` = sum(.$`Class5`),
             Total = sum(.$`Total`),
             .before = 1))%>% 
  distinct()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way doing it with `dplyr` using `bind_rows`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(SUBJECT) %>% 
  bind_rows(summarise(.,
                      across(where(is.numeric), sum),
                      across(where(is.character), ~"All Grades"))) %>% 
  arrange(SUBJECT, Level, .by_group = TRUE)
```

```
SUBJECT Level      Total Class1 Class2 Class3 Class4 Class5
   <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 ELA     All Grades     2      0      0      2      0      0
 2 ELA     Grade 1        2      0      0      2      0      0
 3 ELA     Grade 2        0      0      0      0      0      0
 4 ELA     Grade 3        0      0      0      0      0      0
 5 ELA     Grade 4        0      0      0      0      0      0
 6 ELA     Grade 5        0      0      0      0      0      0
 7 Math    All Grades     1      1      0      0      0      0
 8 Math    Grade 1        1      1      0      0      0      0
 9 Math    Grade 2        0      0      0      0      0      0
10 Math    Grade 3        0      0      0      0      0      0
11 Math    Grade 4        0      0      0      0      0      0
12 Math    Grade 5        0      0      0      0      0      0
13 Sci     All Grades     1      0      0      1      0      0
14 Sci     Grade 1        0      0      0      0      0      0
15 Sci     Grade 2        0      0      0      0      0      0
16 Sci     Grade 3        1      0      0      1      0      0
17 Sci     Grade 4        0      0      0      0      0      0
18 Sci     Grade 5        0      0      0      0      0      0
```

Comment: I always did this with `mutate` and `pivot_longer`, with `bind_rows` is way more readable.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach using `rows_append` by adding the summarized rows:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rows_append(df %>% 
                group_by(SUBJECT) %>%
                summarise(across(Total:Class5, ~ sum(.x)),
                          Level = "All Grades")) %>%
  group_by(SUBJECT) %>%
  arrange(desc(Total), Level, .by_group = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 18 × 8
#> # Groups:   SUBJECT [3]
#>    SUBJECT Level      Total Class1 Class2 Class3 Class4 Class5
#>    <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 ELA     All Grades     2      0      0      2      0      0
#>  2 ELA     Grade 1        2      0      0      2      0      0
#>  3 ELA     Grade 2        0      0      0      0      0      0
#>  4 ELA     Grade 3        0      0      0      0      0      0
#>  5 ELA     Grade 4        0      0      0      0      0      0
#>  6 ELA     Grade 5        0      0      0      0      0      0
#>  7 Math    All Grades     1      1      0      0      0      0
#>  8 Math    Grade 1        1      1      0      0      0      0
#>  9 Math    Grade 2        0      0      0      0      0      0
#> 10 Math    Grade 3        0      0      0      0      0      0
#> 11 Math    Grade 4        0      0      0      0      0      0
#> 12 Math    Grade 5        0      0      0      0      0      0
#> 13 Sci     All Grades     1      0      0      1      0      0
#> 14 Sci     Grade 3        1      0      0      1      0      0
#> 15 Sci     Grade 1        0      0      0      0      0      0
#> 16 Sci     Grade 2        0      0      0      0      0      0
#> 17 Sci     Grade 4        0      0      0      0      0      0
#> 18 Sci     Grade 5        0      0      0      0      0      0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Very nice. I always forget `rows_append()`!

Comment: @TarJae Thanks! Trying to use these more often.

Comment: @Quinten Nice and neat! Lesson learned. Thanks.

Comment: Why `row_append` and not `bind_rows`?

Comment: Hi @MAurélio, You could use both, check Tarjae's answer with `bind_rows`. You could use both.

Comment: What is the difference, both are from `dplyr`

Answer (score 4):

We may use `adorn_totals`

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(SUBJECT) %>%
  group_modify(~ adorn_totals(.x, name = "All Grades")) %>% 
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 18 × 8
   SUBJECT Level      Total Class1 Class2 Class3 Class4 Class5
   <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 ELA     Grade 1        2      0      0      2      0      0
 2 ELA     Grade 2        0      0      0      0      0      0
 3 ELA     Grade 3        0      0      0      0      0      0
 4 ELA     Grade 4        0      0      0      0      0      0
 5 ELA     Grade 5        0      0      0      0      0      0
 6 ELA     All Grades     2      0      0      2      0      0
 7 Math    Grade 1        1      1      0      0      0      0
 8 Math    Grade 2        0      0      0      0      0      0
 9 Math    Grade 3        0      0      0      0      0      0
10 Math    Grade 4        0      0      0      0      0      0
11 Math    Grade 5        0      0      0      0      0      0
12 Math    All Grades     1      1      0      0      0      0
13 Sci     Grade 1        0      0      0      0      0      0
14 Sci     Grade 2        0      0      0      0      0      0
15 Sci     Grade 3        1      0      0      1      0      0
16 Sci     Grade 4        0      0      0      0      0      0
17 Sci     Grade 5        0      0      0      0      0      0
18 Sci     All Grades     1      0      0      1      0      0
```

---

In the `devel` version, we may also use `reframe` with `pick`

```
df %>% 
  reframe(adorn_totals(pick(everything()), name = "All Grades"), .by = 'SUBJECT')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 18 × 8
   SUBJECT Level      Total Class1 Class2 Class3 Class4 Class5
   <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 ELA     Grade 1        2      0      0      2      0      0
 2 ELA     Grade 2        0      0      0      0      0      0
 3 ELA     Grade 3        0      0      0      0      0      0
 4 ELA     Grade 4        0      0      0      0      0      0
 5 ELA     Grade 5        0      0      0      0      0      0
 6 ELA     All Grades     2      0      0      2      0      0
 7 Math    Grade 1        1      1      0      0      0      0
 8 Math    Grade 2        0      0      0      0      0      0
 9 Math    Grade 3        0      0      0      0      0      0
10 Math    Grade 4        0      0      0      0      0      0
11 Math    Grade 5        0      0      0      0      0      0
12 Math    All Grades     1      1      0      0      0      0
13 Sci     Grade 1        0      0      0      0      0      0
14 Sci     Grade 2        0      0      0      0      0      0
15 Sci     Grade 3        1      0      0      1      0      0
16 Sci     Grade 4        0      0      0      0      0      0
17 Sci     Grade 5        0      0      0      0      0      0
18 Sci     All Grades     1      0      0      1      0      0
```

Comment: Thanks for introduce `adorn_totals`. Very neat!

Answer (score 2):

A **base R** approach using `Map`, `rbind` and `split`

```
do.call(rbind, 
  c(Map(rbind, 
    split(df, df$SUBJECT), lapply(split(df, df$SUBJECT), function(x) 
      c(unique(x[[1]]), "All Grades", colSums(x[-(1:2)])))), 
  make.row.names=F))
   SUBJECT      Level Total Class1 Class2 Class3 Class4 Class5
1      ELA    Grade 1     2      0      0      2      0      0
2      ELA    Grade 2     0      0      0      0      0      0
3      ELA    Grade 3     0      0      0      0      0      0
4      ELA    Grade 4     0      0      0      0      0      0
5      ELA    Grade 5     0      0      0      0      0      0
6      ELA All Grades     2      0      0      2      0      0
7     Math    Grade 1     1      1      0      0      0      0
8     Math    Grade 2     0      0      0      0      0      0
9     Math    Grade 3     0      0      0      0      0      0
10    Math    Grade 4     0      0      0      0      0      0
11    Math    Grade 5     0      0      0      0      0      0
12    Math All Grades     1      1      0      0      0      0
13     Sci    Grade 1     0      0      0      0      0      0
14     Sci    Grade 2     0      0      0      0      0      0
15     Sci    Grade 3     1      0      0      1      0      0
16     Sci    Grade 4     0      0      0      0      0      0
17     Sci    Grade 5     0      0      0      0      0      0
18     Sci All Grades     1      0      0      1      0      0
```

Since this is a row based approach, numbers were converted to character. To get numbers back do

```
df2 <- do.call(rbind, 
  c(Map(rbind, 
    split(df, df$SUBJECT), lapply(split(df, df$SUBJECT), function(x) 
      c(unique(x[[1]]), "All Grades", colSums(x[-(1:2)])))), 
  make.row.names=F))

asNum <- Vectorize(\(x) as.numeric(x))

cbind(df2[, 1:2], asNum(df2[, 3:8]))
```

Comment: Thnx for the base R version!